# How do you use UIView with properties or variables inherited from ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have `UIViewController` named **ParentViewController.h** and .m

Then I added `UIView` inside this **ParentViewController**.

I had **uiview.h** and **uiview.h** added and assigned to `UIView` inside **ParentViewController**.

From

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {}
```

which is located in uiview.m, I need to access to properties inside ParentViewController.

How do I do this? Am I using `UIView` wrong?

**ParentViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController

    //I want my uiview to access this variable.
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *usedByUIView; 

@end
```

**ParentViewController.m**

```
#import "ParentViewController.h"
#import "uiview.h"

@implementation ParentViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 ...
}
@end
```

**uiview.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface uiview : UIView
@end
```

**uiview.m**

```
#import "uiview.h"

@implementation uiview

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if(self){
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"start drawing using the data from usedByUIView");
}
@end
```

Comment: The UIView won't have a reference to the containing view controller.  You should simply set any properties on the UIView subclass in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: make use of custom delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few answers on this subject but, summarizing them, you don't, at least not the way that you're doing it. UIView's do not have access to their view controller's and aren't supposed to need access. Of course, in the real world, sometimes it's not worth the overhead of coding around independent views so people hack in access to the controller access. This can be done by keeping an instance variable in the view, pointing to the controller, and assigning a reference to it after the view has loaded, or by overriding the init so you also pass a view controller, or lots of other ways. But before you do that think through the logic of why you want access to the controller from the view and see if there isn't a different way to do it.

Comment: Then how do i call (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {} from ViewController manually? I need to draw something from variables initialized inside the ViewController

Comment: In the controller call [viewname setNeedsDisplay] and this will force drawRect to draw itself (the controller has access to the view; just not the other way around).

Comment: setNeedsDisplay seems to be exactly what i needed! Thank you!